# Create new folder for every EAR file build using jenkins in the perticular directory

Tags: batch-file

I am using batch file to generate EAR file. But every time Its overwriting the previous EAR file. I need to Create new folder for every created EAR file by particular time stamp.

Please help.

Comment: What did you tried as code until now ? post your code !

Comment: hi, i tried with MD %BUILD_NUMBER%_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%. to explain more.. if i have 2 jobs in jenkins and build 1 has happened in job 1 and when i try to trigger build 1 in job2 its giving C:**\.jenkins\workspace\ReviewWorkFlow_Development>MD 14_20150610 A subdirectory or file 1_20150610 already exists.........what i need to do?? from where it is referencing. please help.

Comment: how to create with date & time..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give a better idea here , After analyzing your inputs you are using  Jenkins to build ear files , so use Jenkins Environment variables which comes pre-defined in Jenkins to create a new folder every time.
Place below two lines at starting of your code to build ear file.

`cd %workspace% 
MD "%BUILD_NUMBER%_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%"`

- BUILD_NUMBER - is an jenkins pre-defined variable which has current
  build number of the job which is unique every time.

date command  : will give you date in windows but for formatting additional changes are done. result of date will be YYYYDDMM format

- workspace : is an jenkins pre-defined variable which will give the
  path/location which the build is using i.e physical path of your data.

Comment: Hi , i have 3 jobs in my jenkins. if the build ex 3 is already built in job1 when job2 tries to trigger 3rd build, getting A subdirectory or file 3 already exists. i need BUILD_NUMBER with time stamp

Comment: Hi, C:\*\*\.jenkins\workspace\ReviewWorkFlow_Development>MD 14_20150610 
A subdirectory or file 14_20150610 already exists.........what i need to do?? from where it is referencing. please help

Comment: how to create with date & time.

Comment: found your issue, and the solution would be to use "quotations". Try the updated code above

Answer (score 1):

creates folder in format YYYYMMdd (with highest possible compatibility can be ran on every windows machine since windows 2000 and independent from time settings):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
   set "current-time=%%d"
   set "weekday=%%a"
)
del ~.*
popd
set "current-date=%current-date:-=%"
set "YYYY=%current-date:~0,4%"
set "MM=%current-date:~4,3%"
set "dd=%current-date:~7,2%"

echo %current-time%

set MN=0
for %%# in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
  set /a MN=MN+1
  echo %%#-%MM%
  if "%%#" EQU "%MM%" (
    goto :break
  )
)
:break

if %MN% LSS 10 set MN=0%MN%


echo making directory %YYYY%%MN%%dd%%current-time::=%
md %YYYY%%MN%%dd%%current-time::=%
pause
```

Comment: EAR is generating in C:\ path i need to create a folder ever ytime with time and date so that we don't lose the EAR files for every build.

Comment: @geetha - time also added.

Comment: BUILD_ID is not generating the time stamp